# IIS recover from HD Copy

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, disaster-recovery

i'm here on a new server and want to recover the IIS Role, the old server is as a backup (rsync copy) on a second drive. Anyone know how to recover the IIS from a Directory?

The Server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 in a Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS7+ utilizes XML configuration files so recovering IIS is fairly straight forward.  However, the easiest way if the old server is still online is to [perform a backup and then restore](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration.aspx) it on the new server.

However, you should also be able to find the [XML config files manually and copy them](http://mvolo.com/backing-up-and-restoring-iis-70-shared-configuration/).

Comment: THX for your Answer, it is impossible to recover the whole IIS from a offline HD copy, i can copy the Files but then IIS has wrong encryption Key and the Certificates are also wrong. I recover the IIS step by step from hand and make a Backup with webdeploy.

Comment: Unless you use a higher level backup tool like system restore then yes, you will have to manually go through and recover each part of the server.  Certificates are managed by Windows and are easy to export/import. The machine key on the other hand is a problem. You cannot easily extract this, and all of your encryption in a .NET app by default is based on this key.  It is **HIGHLY** recommended that you specify a specific machine key for each application in a web.config file.

Comment: Now i import the Config with "appcmd.exe restore backup CFGHISTORY_00x" and then the IIS run in the old config but with wrong key. So i go to a new Server and recover the IIS step-by-step. And now i make a Backup with msdeploy every Day to an backupserver :-)